# Prove from first princibles $\frac{x^2-4}{x-4} \rightarrow -5$ as $x \rightarrow 3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am a university student taking a real analysis course and I'm having trouble solving this problem from my question sheet. I'm fairly accustomed to proving sequences from first principles when $n \rightarrow \infty$ but in this question $n \rightarrow 3$.

I've only got so far as my rudimentary...

$$n \geq N \implies \Big|\frac{x^2-4}{x-4} +5\Big| < \epsilon.$$

Which is also confusing as the question was delivered in terms of $x$ instead of the customary $n$. I'm quite confused.

Any tips or a prod in the right direction would be much appreciated, I've spent the whole night pouring through my notes but nothing seems to fit together.

Comment: Do you have this? $$\frac{x^2-4}{x-4}+5=\frac{x^2+5x-24}{x-4}=\frac{(x+8)(x-3)}{x-4}$$

Comment: The statement is equivalent to the function defined by $f(x)=(x^2-4)/(x-4)$ being continuous at $x=3$. The standard way to prove this, would be to establish: 1) Polynomials are continuous everywhere, 2) The inverse of a non-vanishing continuous function is continuous, 3) The product of continuous functions is continuous. If you don't find these results in your notes, and want to start from scratch you could look at each of the steps individually and see how far you get.

Comment: You seem to use $n$ and $x$ interchangeably.  In some places you are thinking of a sequence with $n \to \infty$.  Getting the question right is the first step.

Comment: You don't need to use limits if the denominator doesn't vanish. Just let $x=3$ and you are done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition "$n$ tends to infinity" expresses that $n$ is "as close as you want to infinity" i.e. "as large as you want", and this is formalized by the condition $n>N$ where $N$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Now the condition is "$x$ tends to $3$", and this is formalized by $|x-3|<\delta$ where $\delta$ is positive and depends on $\epsilon$.

The rest of the proof is similar.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the limit of the real function is $lim_{x \to x_0}f(x) = L$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(y)-L| < \epsilon$ for each $|y-x_0|<\delta$, $y \neq x_0$.

For this function it is straightforward as when you give me some $\epsilon$ and need $|\frac{y^2-4}{y-4}-5| < \epsilon$. So I need $|\frac{(3+a)^2-4}{(3+a)-4}-5| < \epsilon$ for $a\in[-\delta,\delta] \setminus 0 $

\begin{equation}
\frac{(3+a)^2-4}{(3+a)-4}+5= \frac{5+6a+a^2}{a-1} + 5 = \frac{11a+a^2}{a-1}
\end{equation}

For $a>0$ we set $a<0.5$ and have to test
$$a\frac{11a+1}{1-a}<\epsilon$$
we see that $\frac{11a+1}{1-a} < \frac{6.5}{0.5}$ and conclude $\delta<min(0.5, \epsilon/13)$

For case $a<0$ we set $a>-1/11$ and test
$$a\frac{11a+1}{a-1}<\epsilon$$

That is equivalent to testing for $a>0$ $a<1/11$ that
$$a\frac{-11a+1}{a+1}<\epsilon$$
so we see that $\frac{-11a+1}{a+1}<1$ and therefore we can set $\delta < \epsilon$.

To conclude for $\delta<min(1/11, \epsilon/13)$ we have proven this from the definition of the limit.

As was mentioned, you can also use the fact that continuous function has a limit in particular $x$ that equals to $f(x)$ if you believe/can show that this function is continuous at $x=3$.

There is also something that in my calculus class was referred as "Heine lemma" but I did not found it on internet in this form. It states that following two claims are equivalent: Function $f(x)$ has a limit $L$ when $x \to x_0$ if and only if the sequence $f(x_0+k_n)$ converges to $L$ for every sequence $(k_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ that converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are familiar with proving a limit for $n \rightarrow \infty$, observe that a limit of the form $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} f(x)$ exists precisely if there is an $L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ that satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n =3$, the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)$ exists, and is equal to $L$. In that case, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} f(x)=L$.

So, for your purposes here, you want to prove that $L=5$ has this precise property. For this, take an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = 3$, and prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_n^2-4}{x_n-4}=-5$.

This should close the gap between your understanding of limits and the exercise at hand. Note that the continuity that is discussed in other answers and comments, is enclosed in the fact that for any sequence $(x_n)$ that tends to 3, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ tends to the same (fixed) number $L$.

Answer (score 1):

As it is not an indeterminate form, the value x tends to can be put directly into the limit. here, answer is clearly -5